# How can I identify what element has the click event and its source code, even it's attached dynamically, ideally in the debugger?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

On a website, when I click a button, it pop a window.

When I inspect the button, it's a DIV embedded in another Div and then another Div.

How can I identify which element has the click event and its source code?

How can I find the place of the source code in the debugger of the browser?